# Direcciones de memoria distintas?

Tags: c, array, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy trabajando en windows 10 y codeblocks, y mi pregunta es porque al hacer esto tengo la posicion de memoria por ejemplo 0060FEFC

> 1º Codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

   int arreglo[4];
   printf("%p\n",arreglo); //Direccion de memoria 0060FEFC
   printf("%p\n",&arreglo[1]);                  //0060FF00
   printf("%p\n",&arreglo[2]);                  //0060FF04
   printf("%p\n",&arreglo[3]);                  //0060FF08

   for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       printf("%p arreglo[%d]\n",&arreglo[i],i); //Direccion de memoria 0060FEFC arreglo[0]
                                                                      //0060FF00 arreglo[1]
                                                                      //0060FF04 arreglo[2]
                                                                      //0060FF08 arreglo[3]


   }

   return 0;
}
```

Pero en cambio si solo pongo los printf se puede ver que empieza por 0060FF00

> 2º Codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){  

    int arreglo[4];
    printf("%p\n",arreglo); //Direccion de memoria 0060FF00 
    printf("%p\n",&arreglo[1]);                  //0060FF04
    printf("%p\n",&arreglo[2]);                  //0060FF08
    printf("%p\n",&arreglo[3]);                  //0060FF0C

    return 0;
}
```

Empieza por 0060FEFC

> 3º Codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int arreglo[4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ ///Direccion de memoria     0060FEFC arreglo[0]
        printf("%p arreglo[%d]\n",&arreglo[i],i);   //0060FF00 arreglo[1]
                                                    //0060FF04 arreglo[2]
                                                    //0060FF08 arreglo[3]
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La explicación es que aunque para ti esos códigos sean prácticamente iguales, el binario resultante puede ser muy diferente... incluso es altamente probable que las posiciones de memoria que te da cambien en función de si compilas con o sin optimizaciones

¿Y cual es la diferencia?

En tu caso la diferencia está en la variable `i`. Ignoro qué compilador y opciones de compilación utilizas, como te digo el resultado es dependiente del compilador y de sus opciones... de hecho, si comparamos los códigos 2 y 3 que son los más sencillos podemos ver bastantes diferencias

## Linux - Clang 6.0.0 - opciones: sin optimizaciones

**Código 2**

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 48
    movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
    lea     rsi, [rbp - 32]
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
    movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
    lea     rsi, [rbp - 32]
    add     rsi, 4
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 36], eax # 4-byte Spill
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
    movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
    lea     rsi, [rbp - 32]
    add     rsi, 8
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 40], eax # 4-byte Spill
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
    movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
    lea     rsi, [rbp - 32]
    add     rsi, 12
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 44], eax # 4-byte Spill
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
    xor     ecx, ecx
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 48], eax # 4-byte Spill
    mov     eax, ecx
    add     rsp, 48
    pop     rbp
    ret
.L.str:
    .asciz  "%p\n"
```

**Código 3**

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 48
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 36], 0
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    cmp     dword ptr [rbp - 36], 4
    jge     .LBB0_4
    movabs  rdi, offset .L.str
    lea     rax, [rbp - 32]
    movsxd  rcx, dword ptr [rbp - 36]
    shl     rcx, 2
    add     rax, rcx
    mov     edx, dword ptr [rbp - 36]
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 40], eax # 4-byte Spill
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 36]
    add     eax, 1
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 36], eax
    jmp     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_4:
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 48
    pop     rbp
    ret
.L.str:
    .asciz  "%p arreglo[%d]\n"
```

## Linux - Clang 6.0.0 - opciones: -O3

**Código 2**

```
main:                                   # @main
    sub     rsp, 24
    mov     rsi, rsp
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 4]
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 8]
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 12]
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
.L.str:
    .asciz  "%p\n"
```

**Código 3**

```
main:                                   # @main
    sub     rsp, 24
    mov     rsi, rsp
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    xor     edx, edx
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 4]
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    mov     edx, 1
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 8]
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    mov     edx, 2
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 12]
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    mov     edx, 3
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
.L.str:
    .asciz  "%p arreglo[%d]\n"
```

Fíjate que una vez aplicadas las optimizaciones los dos binarios son prácticamente iguales... mientras que sin optimizaciones se parecen más bien poco... y resultados diferentes obtendrás al cambiar de compilador... por ejemplo, si compilamos los dos ejemplo scon `gcc 4.4.7` obtenemos:

## sin optimizaciones

**Código 2**

```
.LC0:
    .string "%p\n"
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    lea     rax, [rbp-16]
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    lea     rax, [rbp-16]
    add     rax, 4
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    lea     rax, [rbp-16]
    add     rax, 8
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    lea     rax, [rbp-16]
    add     rax, 12
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

**Código 3**

```
.LC0:
    .string "%p arreglo[%d]\n"
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
    jmp     .L2
.L3:
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    lea     rax, [rbp-32]
    movsx   rdx, edx
    sal     rdx, 2
    lea     rcx, [rax+rdx]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    mov     edx, eax
    mov     rsi, rcx
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
.L2:
    cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3
    setle   al
    test    al, al
    jne     .L3
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

## con optimizaciones

**Código 2**

```
.LC0:
    .string "%p\n"
main:
    push    rbx
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     rsi, rsp
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp+4]
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp+8]
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp+12]
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 16
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

**Código 3**

```
.LC0:
    .string "%p arreglo[%d]\n"
main:
    push    rbx
    xor     edx, edx
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     rsi, rsp
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp+4]
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp+8]
    mov     edx, 2
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp+12]
    mov     edx, 3
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 16
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

Como ves, se parecen más bien poco... a grandes rasgos si tienen algunos detalles en común... pero iguales iguales no son.

No te preocupes por esos detalles ya que la posición exacta de un elemento pocas veces importa... lo realmente importante es que tus punteros apunten a donde deben... las posiciones de memoria son aleatorias y esa aleatoriedad crece conforme se incrementa la complejidad del programa.

Comment: Ahora si me ha quedado claro gracias @eferion

Answer (score 5):

En general, no hay nada que garantice que en cada ejecución del programa la misma variable vaya a ocupar la misma posición de memoria. Por ejemplo, igual si añades parámetros de entrada cambia la posición de memoria. O igual no. El caso es que, aunque veas que siempre obtienes el mismo valor, no puedes confiar en que sea así.

Pero incluso asumiendo que puedes confiar en que obtienes el mismo valor, la cuestión es que los dos programas que muestras son diferentes. Y que la memoria almacena no solo los datos del programa, sino también el propio código máquina del programa. Eso sería uno de los posibles motivos para la discrepancia.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, estaba jugando con el codigo y si declaro el array de enteros como global la direccion de memoria es la misma

Comment: añadi el codigo que me faltaba

Comment: Ahora el codigo ya esta bien

Comment: Tienes razon @SJuan76 pero me parece curioso lo que pasa

Comment: A ver, una de las razones para usar un compilador y un lenguaje de (relativamente) alto nivel como C es precisamente poder despreocuparte de como reservar y usar direcciones de memoria. Con lo cual el compilador suele tener un alto grado de libertad para hacer estas cosas; por ejemplo normalmente es legal cambiar el orden de ejecución de instrucciones mientras el resultado final funcione igual. Puedes tener versiones distintas del programa que acaben siendo el mismo código de máquina, o versiones muy parecidas que acaben siendo notablemente diferente.

Comment: No seria preocuparte? porque lo bonito de c es que puedes manejar la memoria y acceder a bajo nivel, otros lenguajes de alto nivel como python o java tienen recoleccion de basura y la gestionan ellos mismos

Comment: @Juan2005 si haces un programa cuyo buen funcionamiento es altamente dependiente de las decisiones que tome el compilador tienes un problema

Answer (score 2):

Aunque las respuestas anteriores son bastante completas, creo que en este caso una respuesta sencilla puede ser la solución:

El compilador suele colocar las instrucciones del programa en una posición, y a continuación la memoria estática.
Como 2º tiene más instrucciones que traducir (1º y 3º son un bucle con 1 instrucción) su posición en memoria es ligeramente superior.